# wget downloads different file than browser from same URL

Tags: download, http, wget

When downloading the Hard Disk utility tool off [Seagate's website](https://www.seagate.com/de/de/support/downloads/seatools/) I noticed something truly strange.

The Seatools (Linux) link on that site links directly to a .run file which, on my system, firefox doesn't seem to understand as a file to download, instead displaying it as text.

When saving it using "Save link as..." i get the usable installer binary. However when using wget to download the same link, I get a slightly smaller file which cannot be executed due to "exec format error".

What could be the reason for this weird behavior of wget?

Comment: My first inclination is to suggest that there's some sort of encoding/interpretation issue that may require different settings - for example, a DOS/Windows system transferring in ASCII mode may interpret a 0x1A as EOF.

Comment: wget displays plain/text as mime-type which is probably the issue and also why firefox wants to display it first

Comment: => A server misconfiguration; *.run files are not expected to be "binary" (executables)